# Error while including library in android studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-library

Im trying to import floating button library in my project [enter link description here](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)
Im getting an error while building the following

```
Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

I have searched on stackoverflow and one of solutions suggested to comment the line

```
apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

then, the project builds successfully but giving an error on execution

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\GUJAR\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\GUJAR\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\GUJAR\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/getbase/floatingactionbutton/AddFloatingActionButton$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

dependancy :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile project(':floatingbutton')
}
```

help me out...

Comment: show your `build.gradle` code

Answer (score 0):

`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION` usually happens when you have more than one versions of the same library included and gradle have conflict because of that. 
For example if you have jar of some library in you app's `build.gradle` and the same library as maven dependency in `build.gradle` of your library project or vice versa you'll get this error. Take a look on this case.